# SQL Conditional Union Based On Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, union

I have this query which takes in 3 parameters, `StrParameter1` being the one which is key to what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT  ai.strName,
ai.strId,
ai.lngBKey,
ci.strFormattedId,
ci.lngAKey,
ts.dtmPeriod,
ts.strT2Type,
ts.strImpact,
ts.curAmount,
ts.curBalance 

FROM    TBlCInfo ci,
tblAInfo ai,
tblTStage ts 

WHERE   ci.lngAKey    =  ai.lngAKey 
AND     ai.lngBKey    =  ts.lngBKey 
AND     ts.lngVersion    =  0 
AND     ts.blnReversed   =  0 
AND     ai.strType   =   @StrParameter1
AND     ts.dtmPeriod  >= @DtmParameter2
AND     ts.dtmPeriod  <= @DtmParameter3
```

I'd like to union this query with another, but only if StrParameter1 equals let's say, "AAAA". Otherwise, I only want the top portion of the query to fire. There's like 30 other circumstances where I would not need the union, but only 1 where it's needed.

```
Query 1

If StrParameter1 = 'AAAA' Then
    UNION
          QUERY 2
```

Comment: You can't change your query on-the-fly. It does not work like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below pattern to do what you are looking for

```
declare @param varchar(4) = 'AAAA'

select *
from MyTable
union
select *
from MyOtherTable
where @param = 'AAAA'
```

In this case if the @param is 'AAAA', the union will take in to place and if it is not, the second query will not return any result.

So this way you don't need to change your queries.

Comment: @CompSciFly, I don't get what you mean by your second query would still return result. if you set the param = 'AABB', then the second query will not return any rows